# corebluetooth Reading RSSI error:The operation was cancelled

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I'm developing an app using Corebluetooth framework,

and connect to a BLE device to get RSSI value.

I set a function to read RSSI periodly, the timer code is below

```
NSTimer *timer;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.2f target:self selector:@selector(detectRSSI) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and the detectRSSI code is below

```
- (void)detectRSSI
{
    [self.peripheral readRSSI];
}
```

So the question is,

the function works fine , but when I set time interval less then 1.2 sec,

the peripheralDidUpdateRSSI will randomly report error message like this:

```
The operation was cancelled.
```

And it wouldn't happened if the rate is more than 1.2sec.

Does anyone have any idea to read RSSI value more frequently (0.5 sec or less)?

Comment: Perhaps try instead:   peripheral.RSSI

Comment: The RSSI isn't change if I only call [peripheral RSSI] or peripheral.RSSI. The value would be updated after calling [peripheral readRSSI].Finally i found the answer that the limit of reading frequency is define by firmware.

Comment: If you using BLE use `didRangeBeacons:`. The device will only scan so many times per sec.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem as well. For me, it works when I simply add `sleep(2)` inside `peripheralDidUpdateRSSI`. Just don't forget to use background queue when initialising CBCentralManager.

```
- (void)peripheralDidUpdateRSSI:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"RSSI = %@", peripheral.RSSI);
    sleep(2);
    [self.connectedPeripheral readRSSI];
}
```